# Capturar el name del select en HTML y JQuery

Tags: jquery, html

Quisiera saber si hay alguna forma de capturar el valor de `name` de un `select`, es decir que cuando le ponga un `alert` o un `console.log` me salga `1 ó 2 ó 3` ya que no le puedo dar con el `.val` porque lo estoy ocupando para otra función.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Ivan, Como consejo adicional,  no olvidar que **siempre será mejor añadir el código en formato texto y no en imágenes.**

Comment: @Dev.Joel lo que pasa es que el select se llena de forma dinamica

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Esto debería funcionar

```
var optName = $("#cb_unidad option:selected" ).attr("name");
alert(optName);
```

Saludos

Comment: Gracias Totales.

Comment: De nada, si te sirvió no olvides marcarla como correcta. :) Saludos.

Comment: Listo, igual te pido un voto a favor (Y)